# Check if element is in the list (contains)

Tags: c++, contains

I've got a list of elements, say, integers and I want to check if my variable (another integer) is one of the elements from the list. In python I'd do:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4] # elements
my_var = 3 # my variable
my_var in my_list # returns boolean
```

How to do that in C++? I thought of using `std::list`, but I can find no `find` method in it. I can see such method in `std::set` structure.

More deeply, the problem is that my program is given some unique ids (a list, a set, whatever) and I iterate over a long list of input data (ids) and check if they are included in the list (boolean value returned for each iteration step). And I'm not sure how should I do that in C++.

Comment: std::vector. In c++ use std::vector unless you have special reason not to.

Comment: `std::find` is tthe way to look for elements in a container

Comment: Why use a vector if you're looking up values? Surely you'd want a `std::set` or `std::multiset` to give better performance than a linear search unless your list is tiny or you're using a sparse vector and keying on index.

Comment: my list/set would be rather tiny (several elements, less than 10).

Comment: std::find better because it's independent of the container.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can use `std::find`

```
bool found = (std::find(my_list.begin(), my_list.end(), my_var) != my_list.end());
```

You need to include `<algorithm>`. It should work on standard containers, vectors lists, etc...

Comment: ..concise as always with C++. Who needs a trivial method like `contains()`?!

Comment: @Alex: Fixed the naming.

Comment: I feel like adding support for C#-style extension methods would easily fix every complaint I ever made about C++.

Comment: @Jay STL must cover all use cases but be as easy as possible to port between the 70-something platforms C++ runs on. `contains` would be one more method to support that doesn't add any functionality. You're looking for something like Boost.

Comment: c++ solution as usual catastrophic.

Comment: The C++23 solution _finally_ reached the level of concision we all deserve; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77727265/403800.

Answer (score 33):

`std::list` does not provide a search method. You can iterate over the list and check if the element exists  or use `std::find`. But I think for your situation `std::set` is more preferable. The former will take `O(n)` time but later will take `O(lg(n))` time to search.

You can simply use:

```
int my_var = 3;
std::set<int> mySet {1, 2, 3, 4};
if(mySet.find(myVar) != mySet.end()){
      //do whatever
}
```

Comment: `myset.count(myVar) != 0` might be preferable

Comment: std::vector is preferable then - as it will in most cases be quite a bit faster. Don't get fooled just by the Big-O notation, it tells you nothing about the actual speed.
Ifthe vector is sorted it is in general quite a bit faster than set.... and if you are even considering using a set then that also means you can just sort your vector anyways.

Answer (score 9):

you must `#include <algorithm>`, then you can use [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)

Answer (score 9):

They really should add a wrapper. Like this:

```
namespace std
{
    template<class _container,
        class _Ty> inline
        bool contains(_container _C, const _Ty& _Val)
        {return std::find(_C.begin(), _C.end(), _Val) != _C.end(); }
};
...
    if( std::contains(my_container, what_to_find) )
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

A one-liner solution, similar to python, would be `(std::set<int> {1, 2, 3, 4}).count(my_var) > 0`.

**Minimal working example**

```
int my_var = 3;
bool myVarIn = (std::set<int> {1, 2, 3, 4}).count(my_var) > 0;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << myVarIn << std::endl;
```

prints `true` or `false` dependent of the value of my_var.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::find`, something like:

```
if (std::find(std::begin(my_list), std::end(my_list), my_var) != std::end(my_list))
    // my_list has my_var
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare additional helper function like this:

```
template <class T, class I >
bool vectorContains(const vector<T>& v, I& t)
{
    bool found = (std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), t) != v.end());
    return found;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
void Project::AddPlatform(const char* platform)
{
    if (!vectorContains(platforms, platform))
        platforms.push_back(platform);
}
```

Snapshot of example can be found here:

https://github.com/tapika/cppscriptcore/blob/b7f3d62747494a52a440482e841ffb016a3fc56e/SolutionProjectModel/Project.cpp#L13

Answer (score 1):

In C++23, you can simply use [`std::ranges::contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/contains).  Adapting the example therein to lists:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    auto haystack = std::list{3, 1, 4, 1, 5};
    auto needle = std::list{1, 4, 1};
    auto bodkin = std::list{2, 5, 2};
    auto increment = [](int x) { return ++x; };
    auto decrement = [](int x) { return --x; };
 
  assert (
        std::ranges::contains(haystack, 4) &&
       !std::ranges::contains(haystack, 6) &&
        std::ranges::contains_subrange(haystack, needle) &&
       !std::ranges::contains_subrange(haystack, bodkin) &&
        std::ranges::contains(haystack, 6, increment) &&
       !std::ranges::contains(haystack, 1, increment) &&
        std::ranges::contains_subrange(haystack, bodkin, {}, increment) &&
       !std::ranges::contains_subrange(haystack, bodkin, {}, decrement) &&
        std::ranges::contains_subrange(haystack, bodkin, {}, {}, decrement));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since C++20 you can use l.contains(my_var)

https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/more-convenience-functions-for-containers-with-c-20

Comment: You should mention that this only works for associative containers, like `set`, `map`, etc. It won't work for other containers, such as `vector`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31277856)